# Include only *.cs files using the 7zip GUI

Tags: windows-7, gui, 7-zip, parameters

I highlighted a few folders in 7zip and wanted to add only the *.cs files from those folders into this archive.

I can't seem to figure out what I would type in the "parameters" box to make this work.

[image: add to archive dialog]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it *should* be `-ir!.\*.cs` (though I keep getting a `The parameter is not correct.` error).

Comment: I am thinking this just might not be possible via the GUI, thanks for your answer

Comment: That would be strange, I don’t see why it wouldn’t be possible; it even shows it in the help file, and there’s no mention of it in the FAQ. I’ve [asked on the forums](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/forums/forum/45798/topic/4546997), but there are more questions than answers there. Maybe it’s a bug, in which case a [bug report could be filed](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=14481&atid=114481).

Answer (score 0):

According to "Help" documentation, parameters is only for what you would normally pass to the -m switch, ie the Set Compression Method parameters.

So it seems you can't filter files using the GUI (I seem to recall WinRAR being able to though). You could output a txt file with the relative .cs paths then feed that into the CLI version of 7z, but I imagine that's what you were trying to avoid to begin with.