# 7-Zip command line option to include only one kind of file recursively

Tags: windows-7, windows, 7-zip

I want to add any txt file under a given path using 7-Zip.

Looking at the help I tried this:

```
7za a  -ir!*.txt bla.7z c:\initial\path
```

This ended up including every single file, txt or not.

Looking at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/288053/include-only-cs-files-using-the-7zip-gui) I tried to do this:

```
7za a  -ir!.\*.txt bla.7z c:\initial\path
```

This ended up giving me this awkward message:

```
Error:
Duplicate filename:
c:\initial\path\CLI\0003\readme.txt
c:\initial\path\CLI\0003\readme.txt
```

Interestingly the -xr option works fine for me. For example if I try:

```
7za a  -xr!*.txt bla.7z c:\initial\path
```

every file but the txts are included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `7z a bla.7z -r c:\initial\path\*.txt`

You don't need to use the `-i` switch unless you want to include more than one set of wildcards.  In that case, you'd want to you'll want to use multiple `-i` for each set of wildcards on the same command line. But that is a big big pain in the rear and not recommendation.

It is better to output the file paths into a listfile and feed the list of paths into 7z.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is here. [Marco](https://superuser.com/a/1063209/304204)

When you need to include the file path prefix.

Don't use `D:/test/*` or `./test/*` or `-spa`.

Try this conmand:

```
7z a test.7z -ir!"test/*.txt" -ir!"test/*.html"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).