# How do I archive with subdirectories using the 7-Zip command line? Or, how do I KEEP the folder structure while archiving?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I have a bunch of files like this:

```
C:\G\G1\35antique-shop.mp3
C:\G\G2\35antique-shop.mp3
C:\G\G1\09saguri.mp3
C:\G\G2\09saguri.mp3
```

I just want to know how to ***keep*** the folder structure while archiving. This is more important than the duplicate thing, to know how to solve that, would be a bonus.

> @Lamb "Do you want to archive only selective files (not the whole folder content) from the G1 and G2 folders?"

That almost says it all, but I'll try to improve:
Not only do I want to ***move*** only some selected files to an archive. I also have a ***list*** of these files, including path-names to each file.

So, in SubDir1 there might be 10 files, of which I want to zip three, and in SubDir1\sub2 there might be five files, of which I want to zip all five. The files that I need to archive are in a listfile.

There might be duplicate files, so my hope is that with subdirectories added, 7-Zip does NOT see them as duplicates.

And I like to do it on the command line.

I've tried a batch file like this:

```
7z a -r MyArchive.7z C:\G\G1\35antique-shop.mp3
7z a -r MyArchive.7z C:\G\G2\35antique-shop.mp3
7z a -r MyArchive.7z C:\G\G1\09saguri.mp3
7z a -r MyArchive.7z C:\G\G2\09saguri.mp3
```

This also means that files 01antique-shop.mp3, 02antique-shop.mp3, ...., til 33antique-shop.mp3 and 34antique-shop.mp3, should NOT be archived.

The foldernames (=subdirectories) weren't added to MyArchive.7z, and this is the problem.

Obviously, I'd like to use just one commando with a listfile, but that doesn't work either.

I've tried:

```
7z a -mx0 -tzip C:\$$-edrive\F-G-H.zip @fgh.txt
```

which actually works pretty fine as far as the selecting goes, but it does NOT keep the directory structure. Sadly.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to archive only selective files (not the whole folder content) from the G1 and G2 folders ?

Answer (score 17):

The latest stable version of 7-Zip (15.14) has the switch -spf that enables the absolute path storage.

For example, if the file **list.txt** is

```
C:\tmp\dir1\file.txt
C:\tmp\dir2\file.txt
```

the command `7z a p.7z -spf @list.txt` will produce an archive storing the absolute paths as is in the list. Alternatively, the command `7z a p.7z -spf2 @list.txt` will remove the drive letter:

```
tmp\dir1\file.txt
tmp\dir2\file.txt
```

If the file **list.txt** is

```
dir1\file.txt
dir2\file.txt
```

the command `7z a p.7z @list.txt` will store the relative paths as is in the list, in both versions 9.20 and 15.14.

I did more tests with the switch -spf. The results are [here](https://gist.github.com/marko37/1bdc0d8421264d005b81d6e9cff57c39).

Answer (score 10):

I got it to archive a directory with subdirectories [using the following](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples):

```
7z.exe a - t7z NewArchivePath PathOfFolderToArchive
```

Comment: I can't find a direct link to the 7zA.exe anywhere (as per your link), is it obsolete and replaced by 7z.exe?

Comment: @user194767: 7za.exe is the [command-line version](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Comment: and, I'd like to use it, but I can't find a like to it on that page,  7-zip.org/download.html. 
So, just to be clear: 
with **"can't find a direct link to the 7zA.exe anywhere"** I really meant:
**"Please give me a direct link to this free software!"** Thank you!

Comment: @user194767: Ok, [here's](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip) the current version, but are you telling me you couldn't spot **7-Zip Command Line Version** anywhere on that page?!

Comment: I couldn't 7zA.exe so tried using 7z.exe and it worked.  I'm not sure what the -r flag is used for but it is not needed to archive subdirectories.

Comment: @Karan, aha thank you. What with my headless chicken impression and all that, I didn't realize that the already downloaded 7za920.zip contained the 7za.exe, since I was looking for a direct link to 7za.exe, like **7-zip.org/7za.exe** or something similar. I don't know why I did that. But thanks all the same.

Comment: It should be `-t7z` instead of `- t7z`

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead:

```
cd /d C:\
7z a MyArchive.7z G\G1\35antique-shop.mp3
7z a MyArchive.7z G\G2\35antique-shop.mp3
7z a MyArchive.7z G\G1\09saguri.mp3
7z a MyArchive.7z G\G2\09saguri.mp3
```

The problem seems to be that people have been requesting for *years* for proper path storage options (just as they have for the [ability to modify multi-volume archives](https://superuser.com/a/538821/138343)), but the author doesn't seem to be interested. That's part of the reason why I started using WinRAR so much.

---

If you have a listfile, 7-Zip will *not* store paths if the files to be archived do not share a single top-level directory. For example if you have **Input.txt** containing the following:

```
C:\path to\file1.ext
D:\path to\file1.ext
E:\path to\file1.ext
```

If you run `7z a MyArchive.7z @Input.txt`, you'll see that the paths have been stripped completely, which seems completely backwards to me (OTOH `rar a MyArchive.rar @Input.txt` does the job just fine).

So to overcome 7-Zip's deficiency, you can use a batch file as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%i in (Input.txt) do (
    pushd %%i\
    7z a D:\MyArchive.7z "%%j"
    popd
)
```

**Note:** Replace `D:\MyArchive.7z` with the proper path to your destination archive. Also, the batch file should work irrespective of whether you have quoted paths in your listfile or not.

---

**Edit:** If your listfile looks like:

```
"C:\$$-edrive\F\faithless.-.long.way.mp3"
"C:\$$-edrive\G\Antique Shop.mp3"
```

or

```
"\$$-edrive\F\faithless.-.long.way.mp3"
"\$$-edrive\G\Antique Shop.mp3"
```

then edit it to look like this instead:

```
"$$-edrive\F\faithless.-.long.way.mp3"
"$$-edrive\G\Antique Shop.mp3"
```

Now assuming *all* files to be archived are under `C:\$$-edrive`, navigate to C:\ and run `7z a C:\MyArchive.7z @C:\Input.txt`. Using a listfile the paths will be saved *only* if no drive letters are present, no initial backslashes are there and if the top-level (root) directory is the same for all files. Also, for best results I advise you not to create MyArchive.7z in C:\$$-edrive.

Comment: Well, the answer was 3/4 ok. RAR worked super,but batch file worked soso.


Here's the output, and it only added ONE file to my archive, the one without spaces in the filename___



C:\Programs\zippers\7-Zip>(
pushd "C:\
 c:\Programs\zippers\7-Zip\7z.exe a c:\$$-edrive\FGH.7z "$$-edrive\G\gattaca_7mp
3_zefen\gattaca - 03 the one moment.mp3" "
 popd
)

7-Zip 4.65  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009

Scanning

Updating archive c:\$$-edrive\FGH.7z


Error:
Can not open file
FGH.7z.tmp
Access denied.

System error:
undefined error=====

Most important is perhaps the access denied error?

Comment: Can you add a few sample lines (with spaces and without) from your *actual* listfile to your question above?

Comment: okay, so I replaced all the spaces with dots in the filenames, but not in the pathnames, which I will try now.

output is still: 
C:\Programs\zippers\7-Zip>(______
pushd c:\_______
 c:\Programs\zippers\7-Zip\7z.exe a c:\$$-edrive\FGH.7z "$$-edrive\F\filmmusic_14mp3_foretean\starcraft.-.starcraft.vs.south.park.mp3"_______
 popd________
)________


Scanning

Updating archive c:\$$-edrive\FGH.7z

Error:
Can not open file
FGH.7z.tmp
Access denied.

System error:
undefined error

Comment: "I replaced all the spaces with dots in the filenames" - Meaning you renamed the actual files, or just edited the listfile? Spaces in both filenames and paths should be fine, see my edit above (i.e. from your listfile remove C:\ and place quotes around all paths). Now you should be able to use 7z directly instead of my batch file workaround.

Comment: 1. I renamed both = = = = = = 2. I've made your changes, but it still doesn't work with 7z  = = = = = =3. $$-edrive\ is indeed the only top directory. = = = = = 4. Error messages  = = = = = WARNINGS for files:
 = = = = = 
$$-edrive : The system can't find that file. = = = = = 
 = = = = = 
"$$-edrive : The system can't find that file. = = = = = 

 = = = = = 
WARNING: Cannot find 2 files = = = = = 

C:\Programs\zippers\7-Zip> = = = = =

note that there are two warnings, and the second one starts with one double quote... Odd?

Comment: "$$-edrive : The system can't find that file" - Isn't it a directory? Did you add the quotes? Did you run the command from C:\ (i.e. the root, ***not*** from  C:\Programs\zippers\7-Zip)? Is $$-edrive a normal dir or some sort of network mapped deal?

Comment: okay so here's the deal:
If I edit the "C:\" out of the listfile, I get an error telling that the system can't find the file. _______________________________But if I use the listfile,  with the "C:\", then the files **are** archived but withhout a a path. that's back to square one ...

PS i ran the command from a batch file from the $$-edrive folder with the full path for 7z edited into that batchfile.

Comment: So the paths were like "$$-edrive\G\Antique Shop.mp3", and you ran from C:\$$-edrive? Can you *please* run from C:\ instead, as I've mentioned twice already above?

Comment: $$-edrive is a normal dir.

Comment: i moved both batch file  and listfile to another dir, but it still gave the same err message: Can't find that file. and when I add " C:\"  it doesn't keep the dir structure.

Comment: Ok, last time before I have to leave: 1. Remove C:\ from listfile. 2. Ensure file paths have quotes. 3. Go to C:\. Cannot emphasise this enough. C:\. Root dir. *Not* a sub-dir. 4. Run `7z a D:\MyArchive.7z @D:\Input.txt` *directly* from the command prompt (yeah, for best results don't mix the new archive in the same dir where the files to be archived are in). 5. I have tried lots of times by now and it *does* work (with 7za.exe at least). You can confirm and *then* add to a batch file. 6. There, done; am off for now. Hopefully when I check back I will see a check mark next to my answer! :P

Comment: nope, it don't work. no dir structure.

Comment: so, i ran it from the root, but still nothing. I guess im swithching to rar, which kinda suckx

Comment: I don't know why you'd say RAR sucks. Sure it's not free, but on the whole I find it much better in terms of features compared to 7-Zip, and the compression levels are comparable. Also, not to sound condescending, but if my answer's not working for you then you're *probably* doing something wrong. [Here's proof](http://pastebin.com/6k5Qtj3M) that it *does* work, and I have even replicated your fgh.txt listfile and confirmed. Can't say much more than that now, can I, so it's time to move on to something else...

Comment: Worked good for me. It does take a long time though.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a bat script to use with totalcmd "tot-zip.bat":

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "TOP_DIR="D:\Grabovsky""
set "archname="%TOP_DIR%\arch.zip""
set "filelist= "
cd %TOP_DIR%
for %%A in (%*) do (
    set ondisk_path="%%~dpnxA"
    set inarch_path=!ondisk_path:%TOP_DIR%\=!
    echo Putting !ondisk_path! to !inarch_path!.
    set "filelist=!filelist! !inarch_path!"
)
echo filelist: %filelist%

7z.exe a -tzip %archname% %filelist% > NUL
pause
```

Then in totalcmd create a shortcut for it:
[image]

Then when you want to zip some files/folders and preserve folder structure relative to `%TOP_DIR%` you just select the files needed (somewhere inside `%TOP_DIR%`) and press the button.

Answer (score 0):

7-Zip will see them as duplicates regardless, and skip them.  If there's any way to get around that, I've never found it - I always just break the job up into several archives.

Comment: do you know how to KEEP the folder structure while zipping files INTO an archive? They say that's the default, but it's NOT.

Comment: @user194767 - I use a command line like this: `%ZDIR%\7z a -t7z -r -mx=1 %ZIP%\mydocu "c:\My Documents\*.*" -wc:\temp` where `ZDIR` is the path to 7-Zip and `ZIP` is the destination drive.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to help with duplicates.
However, I think a more convenient system than a batch with a full command per would be to create a listfile.txt:

```
 C:\G\G1\35antique-shop.mp3
 C:\G\G2\35antique-shop.mp3
 MyArchive.7z C:\G\G1\09saguri.mp3
 MyArchive.7z C:\G\G2\09saguri.mp3
```

And then compress them all with `7z a -r -tzip archive.zip @listfile.txt`